# How to integrate Unity app into a native android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to integrate a Unity application into android studio project that opens up as an instance upon button click. I am entirely new to android studio, so please keep that in mind when you provide a solution.
My unity app is ready to deploy. Now i just want to create an app on android studio that simply has a button which upon clicking will open the unity app as an instance. If i can do this, i would be able to integrate my app into any other pre-existing android projects without making another version of my app from scratch in android studio.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to integrate an APK/bundle into an android studio project activity and Unity compile a closed source APK/bundle only so it is currently not possible.
You can [broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) one app to open with a button on another app but that will require the user to install both apps.

it *might* be possible on rooted phones but it will probably be pretty complex to achieve

Another elegant solution would be to use something like firebase's [dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/) - that is , your button would open a link, if the user already have the app installed on the device it would open the app (and navigate to wherever) if not, it would open your app's play store download page.